# Appending Raw HTML to variable

Tags: twig

Consider the following script:

```
{% set main="hello" %}
{% set if=1 %}
{% set id=123 %}
{% set extra=456 %}
{{ main~if?" <a href='ku?cf="~id~"&amp;ff="~extra~"'>xxx</a>"|raw }}
```

My desire is to render the following HTML:

```
hello <a href='ku?cf=123&amp;ff=456'>xxx</a>
```

and if `if` is zero, then render the following HTML:

```
hello
```

How is this accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `raw` must be applied to the entire appended variable, and not just the portion of the variable which needs to be escaped.

```
{{ (main~(if?" <a href='ku?cf="~id~"&amp;ff="~extra~"'>xxx</a>"))|raw }}
```